# When I try to make a prediction using a tensorflow.js model I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a webpage that uses a deep learning model to perform live sentiment analysis.

When I use the `model.predict()` function I get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I'm currently using version `1.2.3 of tensorflow.js` and I've tried downgrading the version but it didn't help.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/1.2.3/tf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    async function init()   {
       model =  await tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:8000/model.json');
       model.predict([[tf.zeros(500)]]);
    };
    init();
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
training.ts:320 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at checkInputData (training.ts:320)
    at t.predict (training.ts:1101)
    at t.predict (models.ts:780)
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to come from here `[[tf.zeros(500)]]`. `model.predicts` takes as paremeter either a tensor or an array of tensors in the case the model has several inputs entries.

Depending on the InputShape of the model, `tf.zeros(500)` should be enough or maybe  `tf.zeros(500).reshape(appropriateShape)`